# Add new columns to a dataframe containing sum of positive values in a row and sum of negative values in a row - R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe df which looks like this

```
ID  A  B  C  D  E  F  G 
1   0  0  1 -1  1  0  0
2   1  1  1  0  0  0  0
3   -1 0  1  0  -1 -1 0 
.
. 
.
```

I want to add two column at the end of each row showing the sum of positive values and the sum of negative values so df would look like this

```
ID  A  B  C  D  E  F  G pos neg
1   0  0  1 -1  1  0  0  2   -1
2   1  1  1  0  0  0  0  3    0
3   -1 0  1  0  -1 -1 0  1    -3 
.
. 
.
```

I can't figure out how to do this. I have tried the following which turns the df into a list

`df$neg <- rowSums(df < 0)`

I have also tried the following which throws up an error message:
Error in df[, c("A", "B", "C",  :
subscript out of bounds

`df$neg <- rowSums(df[, c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G")] < 0)`

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try this

```
cbind(
  df,
  pos = rowSums(df[-1] * (df[-1] > 0)),
  neg = rowSums(df[-1] * (df[-1] < 0))
)
```

which gives

```
  ID  A B C  D  E  F G pos neg
1  1  0 0 1 -1  1  0 0   2  -1
2  2  1 1 1  0  0  0 0   3   0
3  3 -1 0 1  0 -1 -1 0   1  -3
```

---

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(ID = 1:3, A = c(0L, 1L, -1L), B = c(0L, 1L, 0L
), C = c(1L, 1L, 1L), D = c(-1L, 0L, 0L), E = 1:-1, F = c(0L,
0L, -1L), G = c(0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
  mutate(pos = rowSums(replace(.[-1],.[-1]<0,0)),
         neg = rowSums(replace(.[-1],.[-1]>0,0)))
```